# Can one un-(vote to close) a question without voting to reopen?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

Scenario (and it actually happened): I was first to vote to close a question as too broad; OP modified the question in such way that my objection did not apply anymore; this modification resulted in further votes to close as not research level, and it has been closed as such. My name is listed among the voters.

I would like to remove my vote to close since in the course of events I described I don't think my name must appear there. At the same time I don't feel like voting to reopen since I am neutral towards the current situation with that question.

Is there a way to remove my username from that list?

More generally, I believe the closing procedure is not quite accurate in that the votes may be for different reasons, and it seems the reason that the majority named is extended to the rest of voters? (Btw what happens if there is no majority, that is, everybody named a different reason?)

Comment: (1) It is the current situation that a closure is based on 5 non-anonymous closing votes. (2) The main technical implication of your vote is that you can't vote again to close it once reopened. Given these points, it would be absurd to be able to cancel a closing vote after closure.

Comment: @YCor Well this means the situation is even more strange than I anticipated

Comment: I certainly agree that the closing procedure is poor, but I think your point is somewhat a minor point, especially because normally the main reason invoked for closing is written with the names of the people who voted for this specific reason.

Comment: @YCor It actually happened several times that my name appeared on the list of close voters with the reason named being the one I did not vote for. I don't think it is appropriate.

Comment: obviously it's not appropriate.

Comment: Close vote can be retracted if you do it *before* the question is closed: [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915) About your previous comment: When a question is closed as off-topic, users who voted to close are listed there along with the reason with most votes, but in a smaller list below only the users who voted for this particular reason are listed: [When is the list of the users who selected a close reason shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188688).